# How to get process names of Installed application

Tags: android, process

Is there any way to get process names of all the applications which are installed on android.
Please help me out.
regards

Answer (score 1):

This gives you all running processes list,

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : apps) {
    String processName = appInfo.processName;
    String appLabel = appInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
}
```

Comment: And how to get application labels?

Comment: Sorry man it dont work. It gives the process name but dont give the application label.